# How to deploy database-per-service pattern

Tags: database, microservices

I'm still learning microservice patterns, but with my understanding, each service should be independently deployed (ie docker container).
So, how does it maintain its database?
How would it connect to it in a fashion that could be stateless?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each microservice must be in its own Docker container. 
Each microservice has its own database connection settings.
Depending on the schema, databases can be created on the database server for each microservice.
Each application instance connects to its own database using its own settings.

You can learn more about the Database per service pattern [here](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html).

Answer (score 2):

The Database per Service (aka Database per Microservice) pattern is a design solution with 3 aspects:

1. **The data "owned" by the microservice is stored in a dedicated data store**, not as part of a shared data store with associations (e.g., FKs) to data elements that belong to other microservices.
2. **The microservice only sees its own dedicated data store**. If the microservice needs data from elsewhere, it should get it through other means, more prominently, API calls or data replication. BTW, service data replication is a separate pattern that may be combined with database per service.
3. **Other microservices and other applications do not see the microservice's dedicated data store**.

[Microservice is an architecture style](https://insights.sei.cmu.edu/sei_blog/2015/11/defining-microservices.html), and **Database per Service is a microservice pattern that may or may not be used for a given microservice**; it is not mandated. Likewise, containerization is almost always a good idea, but it's not a requirement for microservices.